MPAndroidChart phantom legend over landscape legend
I am using MPAndroidChart to chart weather data. The app supports both portrait and landscape modes. The legend looks fine in portrait mode, however in landscape more there appears to be white text, or perhaps a phantom legend, over top of the generated legend. See screen captures.
I cannot figure what is going on ... help!



Turns out the problem was with the definition of the layout in landscape mode. Elements from the main layout were showing up on top of the graph's legend.
